# How to take tab as input from tkinter simpledialog.askstring()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the prompt to return tab character as input

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
a = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Prompt", "Enter Separator", parent = window)
```

However pressing tab or entering "\t" does not work.

Comment: I am having no problem with entering `\t`

Comment: yeah but the result becomes '\\t'

Comment: I am using 3.6.5. If I enter \t it returns '\\t' . if i enter '\t' it returned "'\\t'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Prompt", "Enter Separator", parent = window)` appends a `\` in front of every `\` just to make sure that it is interpreted properly. Hitting Tab Key won't work because tkinter will just switch widgets.

To fix this issue try this before you store the return value of `simpledialog`,
This also solves the question of "How to replace double backslash with single backslash"

```
import codecs
a = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Prompt", "Enter Separator", parent = window)
a = codecs.escape_decode(a)[0].decode('utf-8')
```

This will make sure your `a` variable always has `\t` only.